# Angular login auth what about using web worker?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-authentication

What do you think about this approach

using web worker for angular login/auth

it looks good at me and in this way you can get rid of

$rootScope event as well :)

This is just an example in a more prodution way
you should use like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730809

### Html & js

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="LoginController as vm">
      <p ng-if="vm.isLogged">Logged as {{vm.username}}</p>
      <a href ng-click="vm.doFakeLogin()">Login</a>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>

    function LoginController($scope){
        var vm = this;
        vm.isLogged = false;
        var workerCheckLogin = new Worker('worker-check-login.js');
        var workerDoLogin = new Worker('worker-do-login.js');
        var jwt = 'auth-token';
        workerCheckLogin.postMessage(jwt); 
        workerCheckLogin.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            if(e.data > 0){
                $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                    vm.isLogged = true; 
                    vm.username = 'Whisher';
                });
            }
        }, false);
        vm.doFakeLogin = function doFakeLogin(){
            workerDoLogin.postMessage({username:'whisher','password':'12345'});
        }
        workerDoLogin.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            if(e.data > 0){
                $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                    vm.isLogged = true; 
                    vm.username = 'Whisher';
                });
            }
        }, false);
    }
    angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('LoginController',LoginController);
    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

### worker-check-login.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker check login said: ', e.data);
  /*
   do xhr to the server
   e.data = jwt 
   return 
   1 succees
   0 fail 
  */
  self.postMessage(0); // 
}, false);
```

### worker-do-login.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker do login said: ', e.data);
  /*
   do xhr to the server
   e.data = credentials
   return 
   1 succees
   0 fail 
  */
  self.postMessage(1); // 
}, false);
```