# how to get data from a json file in real time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I try to make this for a long time and i wrote some test script .I use setInterval to update the content once at 500s but i can't acces the inputs for exemple if i have a  form there i don't know how i can write in input without the write been deleted.I use setInterval because i want to see every input from the database .

The index script

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
       <a href="http://php.net/manual/ro/function.json-encode.php"> {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}</a><input type="text" />
      </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     setInterval(function(){$http.get("customers.json").then(function (response) {
          $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      });},500); 
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And the json file

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "City": "Berlin",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Around the Horn",
      "City": "London",
      "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "Name": "B's Beverages",
      "City": "London",
      "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "City": "Luleå",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
      "City": "Mannheim",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
      "City": "Strasbourg",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
      "City": "Madrid",
      "Country": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
      "City": "Bern",
      "Country": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    },
     {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    },
     {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    },{
      "Name": "Bon app'",
      "City": "Marseille",
      "Country": "France"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
      "City": "Bern",
      "Country": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
      "City": "Tsawassen",
      "Country": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
      "City": "Buenos Aires",
      "Country": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "City": "México D.F.",
      "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
      "City": "Bern",
      "Country": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
      "City": "São Paulo",
      "Country": "Brazil"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: seems like a job for a `webworker`

Comment: if you use angular, why you do not use `$timeout` instead of `setInterval` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS and web workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713925/angularjs-and-web-workers)

Comment: i have marked your question as a duplicate, since you probably are just addressing the issue wrong. Please see the link attached to learn how to do it correctly in angular.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713925/angularjs-and-web-workers

Comment: I don't see anything that suggests this has anything to do with web workers. I don't actually understand why you'd expect a json file to keep updating. If you do, probably the solution is to add url parameters to the end so you're not getting it from the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want do real-time application, nodejs + socket.io (websocket) will best fit your needs. Here is an example of how to use socket.io(websocket lib):

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

In addition, any ajax calls will takes time, can easily take more then one second. Therefore, real-time web application need to use websocket instead of transitional ajax call.